# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python

i am installing connector of Psycopg2 but i am unable install, how do i install that successfully?

in using this command line to install:

```
pip install psycopg2


(test) C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\Desktop\projects\purchasepo>pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar
.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shree.shree-pc\envs\test\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Shr
ee.Shree-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Shree.Shree-PC\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\depe
ndency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_l
evel.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Shree.Shree-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_bgz1zs9\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.t
xt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please open a terminal (or DOS prompt) then type python then enter. pls check if you have python in your path. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

command line is correct
path should be checked and perhaps psycopg2 needs a visual C ++ build tools update from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
*I had this problem when I installed python 3.10.0*

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.10:

currently psycopg doesn't support python 3.10

> The current psycopg2 implementation supports:
>
> 1.Python versions from 3.6 to 3.9
>
> 2.PostgreSQL server versions from 7.4 to 13
>
> 3.PostgreSQL client library version from 9.1

source : https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html

and if you're using windows with any version of python but 3.10 please try install psycopg2 by running :

`pip install psycopg2-binary`